# In perl, how do I find the sum of values in 2nd column grouped by values in the first column

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am writing a perl script and am getting the values after many operations as follows:

```
'John', 10, .20
'John', 20, .05
'Paul', 50, .10
'Joe', 70, .03
'Joe', 12, .30
```

Now, I need to do the following operations:

1. Sum up the value of column 2 grouped by column 1.
2. Multiply column 2 by column 3 and find the sum of those answers again grouped by Column 1.

I am trying to see if this can only be accomplished by converting this array into a hash based on the first column or if there is a better way to do this.

Please note that this is not a homework exercise. I have tried to simplify the data by giving masking the original values. The values are of the type given above.

**Expected Output:**

```
'John', 30, 0.1
'Paul', 50, 0.1
'Joe',  82, 0.06
```

Comment: Did you write any code or implement any logic?

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma I tried using a hash, but got lost somewhere in between the hash and arrays and now, don't even understand it. So, did not want to post it here and suggest debugging it. - Karthick S.

Comment: I assume the above data is actually present in individual arrays. Can you please post the expected output?

Comment: Please post it, whatever it will be we'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer while trying to "clean" it for posting here:

My code that works:

```
while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp($_);
    my ($name, $count, $percent) = split("\t");
    $hash{$name}{"count"} += $count;
    if ($count != 0)
    {
        $sonar_out_hash{$name}{"value"} += $percent * $count / 100;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @KrishnachandraSharma for insisting that I post.

Comment: you mean ``split` by comma, yes?

Comment: My original data is a tab separated list, but since I did not know how to add tabs in the the question, I used commas. :)